# Setting up RAID from near-scratch

Tags: windows-10, raid

I am a total newbie on this field but I am planning to set up RAID for my data.

I have a full 1.5TB HDD, a full 2.0TB HDD and an empty 3.0TB HDD, all connected with a Gigabyte GA-H270-HD3 motherboard (which is said to support RAID 0, 1, 5 and 10). Everything will be running on Windows 10 (and a little bit of Linux from time to time), OS which are on an SSD each.

I think I can do software and hardware RAID with that.

Here are my questions :

1 - Is it possible to have those different-sized HDD on Windows 10 ? (this wasn't the case back in the days but what about now ? [Setting up a RAID 5 Array](https://superuser.com/questions/731383/setting-up-a-raid-5-array))

2 - Is it really the end of RAID 5 ? ([RAID 5/10 setup](https://superuser.com/questions/1006417/raid-5-10-setup/1006422#1006422)) RAID 10 seems a lot less interesting and would require a 4th HDD.

3 - Isn't there anything like [Synology SHR](http://nascompares.com/2016/07/06/what-is-shr-and-what-is-the-difference-between-synology-hybrid-raid-and-ordinary-raid/) on Windows ?

Comment: SHR seems similar to Win10's "Storage Spaces". So far I haven't heard bad things about the latter.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are aware, that making a RAID out of a drive will destroy all your data...

Hardware controllers didn't ever complain about different sized drives in one RAID array (never really tested software RAID that extensively). Having 3Ware (LSI, Avago) and Intel controllers, I can tell you it ALWAYS was possible to create raid from different disk sizes, you just lost potentially available space, e.g. in your case you will have RAID5 that has 3TB space available out of 6.5TB on your disks. Noone will stop you doing that though.

RAID5 for +/- 2TB drives is OK IMHO. Enterprise drives 4pieces of 2TB rebuild in under 8hrs AFAIR with no write cache. A software raid 4x4TB NAS drives 5400rpm on freeNAS, with ZFS system, rebuilds at nearly 11hrs. As always, choice is yours. I can only tell you that I've never had two or more drives in one array fail at once thru my 18 years of IT work.... well, only once where power supply blew out and took everything with it, including HDDs.

Comment: Yes I am aware, but does extending my array would do it too ? Like if I get 2 more 2TB HDD and I build a 3 HDD RAID5 array, Could pull my data from my full HDDs and then extend my array with this now empty HDD ?

Comment: Any disk that is freshly included into an array gets it's data erased, so if you have existing array with data on it and migrate this array by adding another disk (either migrating from RAID1 to RAID5 or from 3-disk-RAID5 to 4-disk-RAID5) data will be erased from the added disk only. This process is called migration. If you however try to build new, 3 disk array, of which one already contains data, this data could be lost.  I remember one controller actually allowed me to preserve data from one disk, but I don't remember which one was it and certainly not every controller had that option.

Comment: OK, so I just need 2 empty HDDs to set up a dummy RAID1, and then transfer all the HDD1 data to this volume, then migrate to 3disk-RAID5 with the empty HDD1, then repeat with HDD2. This way I can have my array but I would lose no data, am I right ?

Answer (score 1):

> Everything will be running on Windows 10 (and a little bit of Linux from time to time),

To have both OS's use the arrays, you will need to create the RAIDs in hardware (Fake RAID) because each OS will NOT be able to see the others software arrays.

> Is it possible to have those different-sized HDD on Windows 10 ? (this wasn't the case back in the days but what about now ? Setting up a RAID 5 Array)

With hardware RAID, you will not be able to simply have a single volume spanning all the disks in their entirety very effectively.  RAID volumes spread across drives like to use the same size space in each drive.  You can usually have multiple arrays though (hardware dependent) and many times you can have nested arrays so it might be possible (not necessarily recommended) to raid 0 two 1.5TB sections into a 3.0 TB array via the 1.5TB and 2TB drives, and raid 1 that array with the 3.0 TB drive.  This would leave 500GB of free space on the 2TB drive.

With software raid, pretty much the sky is the limit, then you just have to identify for what cost ($$), what stability, performance, etc.  Some (Linux+MDADM or FreeBSD+ZFS) are very stable and time tested; others (FreeNAS and the likes) are not but can still work well.

Also realize if you create RAID arrays on your motherboard, if your MB fails you will need the same or similar MB to recover your arrays.  RAID IS NOT A BACKUP.

> Is it really the end of RAID 5 ? (RAID 5/10 setup) RAID 10 seems a lot less interesting and would require a 4th HDD.

At the sizes you are talking, RAID 5 would probably be fine.  RAID 10 has the advantage of no parity which carries several benefits, namely performance and increased rebuild success rate, at the cost of one additional drive; but drives are cheap nowadays.  I use non-parity raid (RAID1, or RAID 10) where uptime, performance, and durability are needed, and use parity RAID where increased efficiency is needed.  And technically I have software RAID10's as Linux MDADM RAID10's on 2 drives, not 4.  Point is "the rabbit hole" can go deep.

RAID 10's lack of being "interesting" is what makes it great.  It is simple, cheap and fast.  All things you want if your data matters and gets used.  You do not want complex, slower, and more expensive.  While RAID 5 is "cheaper", it is more complex and slower for writes and rebuilds, and reads not much faster than RAID10.  If you have the physical room, RAID 10 would cost about $30-$60 for the drive (consumer) and $5-$10/yr for the power (24/7 power on time).  Most people find this worth the added benefit.

> Isn't there anything like Synology SHR on Windows ?

This one is more of product recommendation; I don't really have any insight on this.

Comment: Are you sure fakeraid volumes can't be seen between OS'es? I understand it is true for the likes of mdadm and storage spaces, but these bios-controlled fakeraids should still be visible...

Comment: @Kitet I meant to say the opposite, the OS's will need to be on FakeRAID; meaning yes, the FakeRAID should be seen by both.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions:

1. Yes, it is possible to set up a RAID5 on Windows 10 (see, for example, https://www.pcsteps.com/738-software-raid-windows-storage-pools/), however you absolutely **do not** want to do this with the disks you have.  Best practice for RAID 5/6 is to have all disks identical.  If you can't do this, at least have them be the same size.  If your disks are not the same size, the size of the smallest disk will be used as to create the RAID.  In your case, you would end up with a 3TB RAID  (1.5T x 2 + 1.5T parity).  I guess maybe this would be a win (like just having your 3TB disk, but with redundancy), but it sounds like you already have more data than will fit on 3TB, and as mentioned in another answer, creating the RAID will destroy all the existing data on your disks.
2. Why would it be the end of RAID5?  RAID10 is way more resource intensive. Because of the size of modern disks, most people are switching to RAID6, which provides 2 parity disks.  This way if another drive fails during a rebuild, you still don't lose data.  Of course if you have your data backed up and need to maximize storage, RAID5 is still perfectly viable.
3. Synology is a very slightly customized linux system which creates LVM volumes on top of software RAID physical volumes (or just disks, if you don't care about redundancy -- what they erroneously call a JBOD).  I'm pretty sure that if you want SHR you will still be limited to the smallest disk in the group; see the image provided here, for example: http://nascompares.com/2016/07/06/what-is-shr-and-what-is-the-difference-between-synology-hybrid-raid-and-ordinary-raid/.  When using a Synology box you similar want all the disks to be the same size for best results.

Comment: Could you expound on why you think "RAID 10 is way more resource intensive"?  Everything I have heard or read says the EXACT opposite so I think there might be a miscommunication.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer.  By "more resource intensive" I mean RAID10 uses more disks for the same amount of storage.  It's designed to provide one level of redundancy + striping for speed.  Basically, using 4 disks, you create 2 RAID1 mirrors and then stripe data across them.  Comparing to RAID5, if you have 4 x 2TB disks, you get about 6TB of usable storage out of RAID5, but would only get 4TB from a RAID10.

Comment: My question about consistency checking is completely unrelated.  In my experience, patrol reads with hardware RAID are not really noticeable, so it depends on whether you're doing this with a hardware or software RAID.  I have no idea how long a consistency check would take with RAID10, because I never use these.

Comment: --deleted comment--